# Does the Evolution Theory contradict Kant's Metaphysics?

Tags: kant, hegel, evolution, philosophy-of-history, german-philosophy

I recently asked a series of questions about ET, and this is one of them :)

Intuitively, it seems to me that ET is supposed to contradict Kant's (or more generally, the German Idealism's) Metaphysics (historically I've learned that's how it was, a heated debate between the both, with Darwin attacking Hegel's theories and Schelling defending).

But after learning more of the different opinions on ET, I thought it would be good to ask and see what people say about the subject.

The more specific subjects are

a) Kant's moral law

b) Hegel's History of Spirit.

[tell me if you think this should be separated into two questions.]

Edit:

For clarification, when I sat Kant's Metaphysics I mean both the thing-in-itself and the way our consciousness came to be, and the moral law.

Comment: Three comments: First, you should make it more clear *what exactly* you understand under/want to hear about Kant's metaphysics. There is some work on how the third critique is compatible with evolution theory or even presaging it or not. Morals is a whole different story here. Second, left Hegelian interpretations probably are much more ok with the idea of evolution. Third, you should be careful in distinguishing the Theory of Evolution from the general layman idea of evolution. Makes huge interpretational differences  here.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking thanks for the comments. I'll edit the question later to match the first comment, but I'm more interested in the second and third comments - it seems to me that Hegel's theories will have bigger problems with ET than Kant's. And about the third comment - that's the first I heard of such comment, and I'd like it if you'll elaborate more on that.

Comment: Three areas of conflict with this idea are necessity, unity and freedom: The idea that reason evolved implies a contingent origin which conflicts with the necessity of *a priori* concepts. Materialism, as attributed to things in themselves (as opposed to a phenomenal interpretation), is inconsistent with the unity which reason requires. And freedom is necessary for morality and is characterized by an independence from natural determinations. These were among the reasons that led Kant to conclude that we must presuppose a "wise and all-powerful Author."

Comment: @PédeLeão would you care to write this as an answer instead of comment? I'd love to see what other people say about your view too.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss. If you want to know what other people think, you need their words not mine. Anyone who has something to say is free to speak.

Comment: "If there is no original being different from the world, if the world is without a beginning and also without an author, if our will is not free and our soul is of the same divisibility and corruptibility as matter, then moral ideas and principles lose all validity, and they collapse along with the transcendental ideas that constitute their theoretical support." (A468/B496) "Why do we have need of a doctrine of the soul grounded merely on pure rational principles? Without doubt chiefly with the intent of securing our thinking Self from the danger of materialism." (A383)

Comment: @PédeLeão that's not what I meant, when you post it as an answer it'll be easier for people to see and reply to it, and might encourage them to answer on their own.

Comment: Darwin was little known before The Origin of Species came out in 1859. Hegel died in 1831 and Schelling in 1854, there were no heated debates with them. If anything, Hegel's introduction of evolving concepts into metaphysics prepared the cultural ground for the evolution theory, Kant's system was essentially static, but neo-Kantians revised it to incorporate evolution without much trouble.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that Kant and Hegel would be perfectly happy with Darwin's biological evolution. They may not be happy with everything that is claimed in the name of Darwin but that's another story.

Comment: @Conifold I've read that Schelling defended Hegel in front of Darwin when Darwin introduced his theory to the University (I don't remember which, probably Berlin).

Comment: @PeterJ "They may not be happy with everything that is claimed in the name of Darwin" - could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please provide the source, the timeline does not work for Schelling to do it in person, Agassiz, a follower of Schelling, publicly opposed Darwin. It is known that Darwin was influenced by Humboldt, a biologist partial to Schelling, but Schelling's evolution was driven by cosmic "creative force", not natural selection. Wandschneider, a modern Hegelian, argues that evolution theory needs to be complemented by "ideal logic" behind the natural forces, see [Darwinism & Philosophy](http://ndpr.nd.edu/news/darwinism-philosophy).

Comment: @Conifold A) thanks for the referral, I'll read it. B) you're probably right. Maybe it was Agassiz who I read about.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - I was just noting that Darwin's followers added to his theory and that some of what is now thought of as Darwinian evolutionary theory was unknown to him. A small point. For instance, his view of consciousness was less dismissive than it became later, which may be relevant here. .

Comment: @PeterJ it is relevant :) Personally I don't know the original Darwinism and what was added since then, so if you can elaborate I'll be greatful.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - We need a new thread for this. Perhaps it deserves a question of its own. On consciousness, Darwin was quite happy to concede a role for consciousness in determining behaviour and thus the selection process and the emergence of traits, but later biologists became a lot less happy to do so. It's a contentious issue too big for the comment section.  .

Comment: @PeterJ sure I'll open a different question for this. Though it honestly have much relation to this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

## These things are *entirely* unrelated

[Darwin's Theory of Evolution Through Natural Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species) concerns the [**formation of biological species**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciation).

[Kant's moral law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantian_ethics) does not concern speciation.

[Hegel's Phenomenology of Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phenomenology_of_Spirit) does not concern speciation.

Your question is as nonsensical as if to ask of [the theory of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity) disproves the ethical arguments for [the Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule).

Comment: It may not necessarily conflict, sure, and I'm hoping you've seen the discussion on it in the comments to the question. Either way, note Pé de Leão's first comment on where precisely it might conflict.

Comment: I did not say they are in conflict, I said these works are **unrelated**. The theory of evolution is a scientific theory about a very specific area of biology. Kant and Hegel does not make any proclamations about that. The fact that Darwin may have debated **other subjects**, subjects that Hegel and Kant have an interest in and have made statements about, does not mean that the theory of evolution is in the least related to those other subjects. In short: **Darwin does not personify the Theory Of Evolution**. Darwin is a person that presented a theory. The theory is separate from the person.

Comment: Again, the works themselves may be unrelated, but they can have conflicting conclusions. Reliability isn't my concern here.

Comment: If they are unrelated and deal with unrelated subject areas they cannot have conflicting resolutions. A conclusion about how species form can **impossibly** be in conflict with a statement that does not deal with speciation at all. The post should be edited or closed, because you have not even shown that these works connect in any way.

Comment: Have you even looked at the comments to the question?

Comment: Yes I have, and if you want to show any claim that Kant or Hegel made that would be invalidated by The Theory of Evolution, then by all means edit that into the question. But do note this: **unless** they argue that their theories are  **depending** on the notion that the theory of evolution is non-existent, then these works are unrelated.

Comment: Again, I'm **not** saying that Kant or Hegel's works intrinsically reject ET, I'm saying that their works have conclusions that *might*. If you want an example, a simple one would be free will, which is very hard to come by when you consider that evolution is random, thus your very existence is random, and is 'controlled' by biological/'natural' notions. Another would be that reason (along with the brain) evolved over the history, and wasn't "given" in a form of a priori concepts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75242/discussion-between-michaelk-and-yechiam-weiss).